# Ubercart Multiple Taxes Error

Tags: 7

I have a question concerning Multiple Taxes with multiple content types in Ubercart 3 on Drupal 7.

I have 2 different tax rates:

- 8%
- 2,5%

and 2 content types or product classes

- Products food
- Products accessories

I want to apply the tax rate 8% to product accessories and 2,5% to products food and I woked around "Conditions" in order to do that, but, when I complete the order form my cart and go to checkout I obtain something like that:

```
Subtotal: 29.00 CHF
Colis Standard: 10.00 CHF
Subtotal excluding taxes:39.00 CHF
TVA 8%: 2.32 CHF
TVA 2,5%: 0.06 CHF
Order total: 41.38 CHF
```

In this case (above) in my cart I have just one item of ***product accessories*** ( with an 8% TVA ) and nothing else.

If, on the other hand, I buy one or more items for ***product food*** I get this:

```
Subtotal: 9.00 CHF
Colis Standard: 10.00 CHF
Subtotal excluding taxes: 19.00 CHF
TVA 2,5%: 0.23 CHF
Order total: 19.23 CHF
```

No 8% VAT was included in this case...

If I change weight of tax rates, on the contrary, I obtain this:

```
Subtotal:   9.00 CHF
Colis Standard: 10.00 CHF
Subtotal excluding taxes:   19.00 CHF
TVA 2,5%:   0.23 CHF
TVA 8%: 0.02 CHF
Order total:    19.24 CHF
```

My question is:
How can I apply related Tax Rate to each line item of the cart/order based on content type or product class?

Example

my product accessories: 10 CHF + 8%

my product accessories: 5 CHF + 2.5%

my other product accessories: 13 CHF + 8%

Total......

I hope I explained myself.

Thanks in advance!!

............................................FIXED!

Ok, I guess I found the solution...
I had to uncheck "Tax" checkbox in **Taxed line items** 
Thanks anyway!

CYA

Comment: can you give me the exact name of the module? thank you

Comment: Hi, the module is the one provided by default with Ubercart 3.0 Package and it's uc_taxes. It wasn't necessary to install anything else but just work around module settings.